# Navigation Drawer Menu Item Title Color in Android

Tags: android, colors, navigation-drawer, menuitem, android-navigationview

I have a problem changing the Menu Item Title `Color` in the `Navigation Drawer` I set the `itemTextColor` but it only changes the `Color` of the Items not the `Title` of the menu.

Here is my 
**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:itemTextColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#283135"
        />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**activity_main_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@mipmap/hospital"
            android:title="Home"
            />
<item
            android:id="@+id/nav_reminder"
            android:icon="@mipmap/alarm"
            android:title="Reminders" />

    </group>

    <item android:title="Tools">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
                android:icon="@mipmap/settings"
                android:title="Settings" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_help"
                android:icon="@mipmap/information"
                android:title="Help" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_about"
                android:icon="@mipmap/team"
                android:title="About Us" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

**Check this:**[image: This is the one i am talking about]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To give `Menu` item `title` `color` and `textSize` Create this way..

add this to your `styles.xml` file.

```
 <style name="TextAppearance44">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
 </style>
```

now in `activity_main_drawer.xml` file give `id` `attribute` to `title`..

```
<item android:title="Tools"
       android:id="@+id/tools">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
                android:icon="@mipmap/settings"
                android:title="Settings" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_help"
                android:icon="@mipmap/information"
                android:title="Help" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_about"
                android:icon="@mipmap/team"
                android:title="About Us" />
        </menu>
    </item>
```

now In `MainActivity.java` file use this way..

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();

        MenuItem tools= menu.findItem(R.id.tools);
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString(tools.getTitle());
        s.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(this, R.style.TextAppearance44), 0, s.length(), 0);
        tools.setTitle(s);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

It will change your `tools` `color` to `Red` and `TextSize` to `20sp`.. Implement it..

In my case Output :

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i need that one too

Answer (score 23):

You can also define new style in styles.xml:

```
<style name="NavigationView">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

and then applying this style in NavigationView's theme:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:theme="@style/NavigationView" />
```

Comment: it's weird, but this implementation changes the icon tint. It leaves the text color untouched. LOL! such inconsistencies...

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere, yes it was executing the same behavior for mine too. So, I added another answer where to exactly put it the right way, without using custom theme too.

Answer (score 6):

Just add  `app:itemTextColor="@color/accent` property in your Navigation view tag like below.

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/accent"/>
```

Comment: how do you put `app:itemTextColor` into a style ?

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who may stumble upon this question and find no working answer like me, add `<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>` inside your `AppTheme` and `AppTheme.NoActionBar` styles.xml file like this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    </style>
...
</resources>
```

This should produce something like this:

[image: navigation drawer custom styling]

Note: I've made the item text "Share" or "Send" white by adding `app:itemTextColor="@color/white"` inside the `NavigationView`. The Full NavigationView code:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
            android:background="#283135"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

With the [`NavigationView`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/NavigationView.md) included in the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android)  you can use the **`app:itemTextColor`** to define a color or a selector for each items and the `app:itemTextAppearance` if you want to customize the TextAppearance used.

```
 <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView    
      app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
      app:itemTextAppearance="@style/...."
      ...>
```

For the color you can use a selector like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

[image]

To change the color of a **title group** you can override the **`android:textColorSecondary`** color with:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.titleColor"
    ..>
```

with:

```
  <style name="ThemeOverlay.titleColor" parent="">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/....</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="AppTheme.NavigationView">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

Set textSize if you want to change the title size too