# Change background color of specific items in Material navigation view

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I am new to using Navigation Drawer and I want to change the background color of specific menu items in my navigation-view.

I want to do something like this:

[image]

In this image navigation items like Products have different background.

I have searched for the solution, but only one i found is by using Recyclerview instead of NavigationView.

But I want to stick with nav view.

Some help will be really appriciated.

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216457/navigation-drawer-menu-item-title-color-in-android ?

Comment: if not then I am working on it, I guess style will do this magic

Comment: sorry mate I give up on this one, if It is possible with nav_view, I would be the first one to update it.